# JavaScript create an object like {Dogs: []} where "Dogs" is passed in as a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to create an object like `{Dogs: []}` where `"Dogs"` is passed in as a variable. I need to add my new object to this.state.

Then, I need to add objects to the array I've created. The new objects are in the form

```
{Dogs: [{name: "Fido"}, {name: "Snoopy"}]}
```

In this stage, the strings `"Fido"`, `"Snoopy"`, will be passed in as variables, and "Dogs" is passed in as a variable as well.

The syntax is defying me...

Comment: @Barmar: What property **names** in the question are dynamic?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `Dogs`.

Comment: @Barmar: Gah, buried in the title!

Comment: `var myObj = {}; myObj["Dogs"] = [ ... ];`

Comment: @MatteoTassinari: Or as of ES2015+: `var dogs = "Dogs"; var myObj = {[dogs]: [...]};`